# Are these statements equivalent?

Tags: java, refactoring, boolean-logic, demorgans-law

Can I refactor like this, are these equivalent and therefore the simpler straighforward version of the code is preferred?

Before refactoring:

```
    if (!matcher.matches() && !matcher2.matches() && !matcher3.matches()
            && !matcher4.matches() && !matcher5.matches()
            && !matcher6.matches() && !matcher7.matches()
            && !matcher8.matches()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
```

After refactoring:

```
    return (matcher.matches() || matcher2.matches() || matcher3.matches()
            || matcher4.matches() || matcher5.matches()
            || matcher6.matches() || matcher7.matches()
            || matcher8.matches())
```

Comment: Yeah, pretty much: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws (You might have to apply an extra inversion at the end. I haven't checked though.)

Comment: Actually, any IDE that's worth anything will perform this refactoring for you. Eclipse using Ctrl + 1 and IntelliJ using Alt + Enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. You have to add `!` in front of the second option.

The fixed second option is more clear for sure:

```
return !(matcher.matches() || matcher2.matches() || matcher3.matches()
            || matcher4.matches() || matcher5.matches()
            || matcher6.matches() || matcher7.matches()
            || matcher8.matches())
```

I will also refactor it this way:

```
boolean atLeastOneMatch = matcher.matches() || matcher2.matches() || matcher3.matches()
                || matcher4.matches() || matcher5.matches()
                || matcher6.matches() || matcher7.matches()
                || matcher8.matches();

return !atLeastOneMatch;
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, no. The first one is `true` only when all matchers **don't** match. If all matchers don't match in the second statement, you return `false`

```
return !(matcher.matches() || matcher2.matches() || matcher3.matches()
            || matcher4.matches() || matcher5.matches()
            || matcher6.matches() || matcher7.matches()
            || matcher8.matches())
```

This is correct

Answer (score 0):

No, these are not equivalent.  Pare it down a bit so it's clearer - let's use just 2 examples, and make them x and y instead of "matcherX.matches()".  You're asking, in that case:

Are these two equivalent?

```
if (!x && !y) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
```

and

```
return (x || y);
```

Let's ease our way into it.  First, the initial statement can clearly be transformed directly to

```
return (!x && !y);
```

Here's the [Truth Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) for that:

```
|    x    |    y    |  !x && !y  |
+---------+---------+------------+
|    T    |    T    |     F      |
|    T    |    F    |     F      |
|    F    |    T    |     F      |
|    F    |    F    |     T      |
```

That is, the first expression returns `true` only when none of the subexpressions is true.  That's the same as

```
return !(x || y);
```